# Newtonsoft.Json Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'StaticPasses', line 1, position 178

Tags: c#, json, rest, http

i'm having this issue trying to send JSON to my REST API. I don't think it's an issue with the method itself because it seems to run fine when I call the endpoint in postman. When I call the endpoint using HttpClient, it results in the error below.

```
Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'StaticPasses', line 1, position 178.
```

Here's my JSON:

```
{"Id":0,"Email":"teststaff@test.com","Name":"TestStaff","Password":"Password","SchoolId":3,"StaticPasses":"[{\"QrCode\":\"https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=http://hallpass.azurewebsites.net/api/pass/getstaticpass/0/3/0\",\"Id\":0,\"Staff\":0,\"Student\":-1,\"ExpirationTime\":\"00:00:00\",\"CreationTime\":\"02:37:28.2114320\",\"Destination\":\"Destination\",\"ShareCode\":\"0\"},{\"QrCode\":\"https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=http://hallpass.azurewebsites.net/api/pass/getstaticpass/1/3/0\",\"Id\":0,\"Staff\":0,\"Student\":-1,\"ExpirationTime\":\"00:00:00\",\"CreationTime\":\"02:38:01.8744350\",\"Destination\":\"Destination\",\"ShareCode\":\"1\"}]"}
```

Again, the JSON seems to work perfectly in Postman, but doesn't work in my code.

Here's the call to the server:

```
string staffJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(staff);
var response = await client.GetAsync("schools/updatestaff?staff=" + staffJson);
```

If anyone can tell me what is wrong with the JSON or the call, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Is StaticPasses an array or a string? Because if it's supposed to be an array then it should look like `"StaticPasses": [{"QrCode":"http....", "Id":0,"ShareCode":0},{“QrCode":"http..."}]` obviously I omitted a bunch. But notice I didn't need to double escape things etc

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Newtonsoft.Json doesn't like when you contain a link in a string and throws out that error. I solved the problem by just shortening my links to just hold the information for their endpoint.

Comment: It seems to me like it is a problem of escaped/non escaped quotation mark "